# How to ignore "$" in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

my table looks like this:

```
create table MOCK_DATA (
  id INT,
  employeeID VARCHAR(50),
  first_name VARCHAR(50),
  last_name VARCHAR(50),
  phone VARCHAR(50),
  email VARCHAR(50),
  gender VARCHAR(50),
  country VARCHAR(50),
  city VARCHAR(50),
  salary VARCHAR(50);

    insert into MOCK_DATA (id, employeeID, first_name, last_name, phone, email, gender, country, city, salary) 
values 
(1, '61-8930771', 'Piotr', 'Haglinton', '1(564)296-4462', 'phaglinton0@cbslocal.com', 'Male', 'Canada', 'Waterloo', '$6862.20');
```

The query i want to run is:

```
select distinct mock_data.employeeid,
               mock_data.salary
  from MOCK_DATA
  where mock_data.gender like 'M%' and
        replace(salary, '$','') salary > '3400';
```

Because the salary field contains a character i cannot use relational operators, so i first used replace to change the "$" to ""

The error i get when i run the above query is:
ORA-00920:: invalid relational operator

How should my query look like ?

Comment: Storing a numeric value as a string: there's your real problem.

Comment: Agree. Store it as a double and handle the currency type in the application logic.

Comment: i understand that in the example above it would be correct to store the salary value as numeric without $, but in my real life table there is a different case where i must have both characters and numbers in the same cell, and i need to filter results based on the number value

Comment: No! Storing it as string is actually ALWAYS wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query.

```
select distinct employeeid,salary 
from MOCK_DATA 
where gender like 'M%'
  and replace(salary, '$','') > '3400'
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed and i didn't understand. I thought that
"replace(salary, '$','') salary > '3400';" is correct but in fact, the correct way is without the second "salary"

Comment: This will fail with many values –  '9' is greater than '1000' – when processed as a string. You need to do a conversion (eg. `cast` operator).

Comment: I have executed this query in a table of 10.000 randomly generated rows with random generated values, it has displayed all the correct data.

@Richard: i did indeed used cast :cast(replace(salary, '$','') as decimal(10,2))

Comment: This is completely wrong. If salary = $500, then the query will return '500' > '3400', because it will be an ALPHABETIC comparison, which assesses each character left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Your data and query is so bad that you should throw it away and start again.

Firstly, don't every try to compare numbers as strings. Think about what will happen if someone happens to have a salary of 10,000.

Your query should use something like:

cast(replace(salary,'$','') as decimal(10,2)) > 3400

That said, you've still got worse problems.

A small, slap-on-the-wrist problem is that you've stored everything as varchar(50). Is that really the case, or is "50" just the first number that popped into your head?

An offence punishable by death is that you're storing a number as a string. Fix your column data type, get rid of the '$', and your life will become much easier.

Comment: thank you for your answer. as i said above, the example above is just something i generated quickly to be able to post it as an example, it should not be taken as fact. 50 was the default value generated by mackaroo, and i didn't change it.

Also, the test data had salary interval of 500 - 9999, so it couldn't have 10.000.

again, i understand having number as string is bad, but consider that instead of salary field it would be a phone number as "555-1234-11" which also has characters in it and it might be needed to to ignore those